# A question based on use of Maximum Modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

This question was asked in comprehensive which I am doing .

> Let $\Omega$  be a bounded region and g $\in C(\bar\Omega) \cap H(\Omega)$. Assume that |g| is a non-zero constant on $d\Omega$ . If g is not constant on $\Omega $ then show that g has atleast 1 one zero in $\Omega$ .

Maximum modulus principle can be used and using hypothesis |g| is constant let c  on $d\Omega$. So, max g $\leq$ c . But I am not able to proceed from this.

Note: This question has an answer here:[Suppose $|f|$ is constant on $\delta D$. Show that $f$ has at least one zero in $D$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303747/suppose-f-is-constant-on-delta-d-show-that-f-has-at-least-one-zero-in)

but I couldn't deduce how Question asker wrote that 1/f will not be holomorohic using Maximum principleprinciple and user 622... was last seen 7years ago. So, I don't think I should ask him.

Kindly tell how should I approach this question.

Comment: Suppose $g$ does not have zeros. Then consider $\frac{1}{g}$, and apply the maximum modulus principle

Comment: @Caffeine kindly look at edit. It was in the edit process. Apologies for inconvenience!!

Comment: $\frac{1}{g}$isholomorphic.As such,its maximum will be onthe boundaryof$\Omega$,and since gis constant there,$\text{max}\frac{1}{|g|}=\text{max}|g|$. Do you see why this implies that g is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $|g|=c\;\,$on $d\Omega$.

By the maximum modulus principle, we have $|g(z)|\le c$ for all $z\in\overline\Omega$.

Since $g$ is holomorphic and non-constant on $\Omega$, $g(\Omega)$ must contain a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

It follows that $|g|$ is non-constant on $\Omega$, hence if $b$ is the minimum value of $|g|$ on $\overline\Omega$, we must have $b < c$.

Suppose $b > 0$.

Then $g(z)\ne 0$ for all $z\in\Omega$.

Hence by the minimum modulus principle, the minimum value of $|g|$ on $\overline\Omega$ must occur at some $z\in d\Omega$, contrary to $b < c$.

Therefore $b=0$.